# android restful webservice send array of data into php and retrive data in server

Tags: php, android, web-services, rest

I want to send array of values from android to php to insert in to MySQL database.Here is my android code.

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    for (String receiver : receivers) {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receiverid", receiver));
    }
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senderid", args[0]));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject", args[1]));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", args[2]));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msgdt", args[3]));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msgtime", args[4]));
    // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receiverid[]", args[5]));

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
            Constants.URL_admin_send_message, "POST", params);

    try {

        // JSONArray categories = json.getJSONArray("success");

        String val = json.getString("success");

        if (val.equals("1")) {
            status = true;

        } else {
            status = false;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here is my php code.

```
try
```

{

```
$receiverid =array();
$s="";
$senderid =$_POST['senderid'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

$msgdt=$_POST['msgdt'];
$msgtime =$_POST['msgtime'];
$receiverid =$_POST['receiverid'];
$response = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($receiverid);$i++)
 {

$s=mysql_query("insert into `schoolsystem`.`sch_message` 
( 
`sender_id`, 
`subject`, 
`message`, 
`msg_date`, 
`msg_time`, 
`receiver_id` 

)
values
(
'$senderid', 
'$subject', 
'$message', 
'$msgdt', 
'$msgtime', 
'$receiverid[$i]')");

}
```

I dont get the all the values that i had sent from my android code.The for loop in php works only one time so i only get one value in $receiverid[$i] . Only get one value.. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a parameter to be an array you have to include [] in the parameter name. replace `receiverid` with `receiverid[]`.